# Prove that $R_1 \cup R_2 \cup (A_1 \times A_2)$ is antisymmetric on $A_1 \cup A_2$.

Tags: proof-verification, relations

> Suppose $R_1$ is a partial order on $A_1$, $R_2$ is a partial order on
>   $A_2$, and $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$.
>
> Prove that $R_1 \cup R_2 \cup (A_1 \times A_2)$ is antisymmetric on
>   $A_1 \cup A_2$.

**Proof:** Suppose $(x,y) \in R_1 \cup R_2 \cup (A_1 \times A_2) $ and $(y,x) \in R_1 \cup R_2 \cup (A_1 \times A_2) $ with $x,y \in A_1 \cup A_2$.

Case $(x,y)\in R_1 \cup R_2$:

SubCase1: $(y,x) \in R_1 \cup R_2 $. Because $(x,y)\in R_1 \cup R_2$ and since we know $R_1 \cup R_2$ is antisymmetric, it follows that x=y.

SubCase2: $(y,x) \in (A_1 \times A_2)$. Then $y \in A_1$ and $x \in A_2$. Because  $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$, $y \notin A_2$ and $x \notin A_1$.

---

At this point , I don't know how to show if given $(y,x) \in (A_1 \times A_2)$ and $(x,y)\in R_1 \cup R_2$ hold, then x=y, if it's even possible to show.

Answer (score 1):

(Getting another question off the unanswered list.)

The trick at that point is to recognize that the troublesome case cannot actually occur. In fact, I’d organize the argument to dispose of that case first.

For convenience let $R=R_1\cup R_2\cup(A_1\times A_2)$, and note that $R_1=R\cap(A_1\times A_1)$ and $R_2=R\cap(A_2\times A_2)$, while $R\cap(A_2\times A_1)=\varnothing$.

Suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle y,x\rangle\in R$. If $\langle x,y\rangle\in A_1\times A_2$, then $x\in A_1$ and $y\in A_2$, so

$$\langle y,x\rangle\in R\cap(A_2\times A_1)=\varnothing\,,$$

which is impossible, so this case cannot actually occur. Thus, $\langle x,y\rangle\notin A_1\times A_2$, meaning that either $\langle x,y\rangle\in R\cap(A_1\times A_1)=R_1$, or $\langle x,y\rangle\in R\cap(A_2\times A_2)=R_2$.

Suppose, then, that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_i$ for some $i\in\{1,2\}$. $R_i\subseteq A_i\times A_i$, so $\langle x,y\rangle\in A_i\times A_i$, and therefore $x,y\in A_i$. But then $\langle y,x\rangle\in R\cap(A_i\times A_i)=R_i$, and $R_i$ is antisymmetric, so $x=y$.